# How to manually install Google Data Python library?

Tags: python, installation, google-data-api

I don't know how to install Google Data Python library, and I'm not a programmer either. I don't understand the Google Developers guide and on YouTube, the guy doesn't show how he install it (scripts maybe) on the python.

I tried [Getting Started with the Google Data Python Library](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib), but I'm only at step 2.

I'm stuck at "Installing the Google Data Library":

> Download the Google Data Python library if you haven't done so. Look for the latest version on the Python project's downloads page.
>
> After downloading the library, unpack it using `unzip` or `tar zxvf` depending on the type of download you chose.
>
> Now you are ready to install the library modules, so that they can be imported into Python. There are several ways you can do this:
>
> - If you have the ability to install packages for all users to access, you can run `./setup.py install` from the unpacked archive's main directory.
> - If you want to install these modules for use in your home directory, you can run `./setup.py install --home=<your home directory>`

Comment: No offense meant, but if you can't follow the relatively simple instructions on how to install it, how do you think you will be able to write the code to use it once you have done so?

Comment: what are you ultimately trying to do? i mean, what project/task do you want to use this for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, download the Google Data Python library, then double click the file in your Downloads directory, which will automatically unpack it, regardless of whether you downloaded the .zip or .tar.gz version of the file.

Next, open Terminal, `cd` to the directory where the library has been installed (e.g.: `cd ~/Downloads/gdata-2.0.18`), and try running the commands they mention.

If the second paragraph doesn't make any sense to you, go here: http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ and all will become clear. Don't worry, it's not book-length.

Comment: Thank you Zodiak770, you are so kind. I tried the second paragraph (eg.: cd ~/Downloads/gdata-2.0.18) but its not working. Im sorry if Im annoying I just dont know how these things work. Ill read the site you provide. Thank you.